# Multiple selections field for touchscreen device

Tags: usability, gui-design, user-expectation, user-research, usability-testing

i'm trying to find an intuitive way to display a multiple products selector.

The user has the possibility to select multiple product in the following screenshot.

[image]

The problem is that most of the users in the user testing sessions just select one product and ignore selecting other products (even though it was required in the task to select 2 products).

Any ideas are welcomed :)

Comment: Have you considered altering the copy? Maybe instead of "Select products" tell the users "Please select at least two (2) products". 

Also, during user testing have you asked your users why they only selected one product? What was their thinking during the selection?

Comment: Minimum is 1. I've also asked the users in 3 separate testing sessions to describe me that screen. They failed to notice that was a multiple selection.

Also the first screen is with none selected and the continue button disabled.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, following up from your answer:

1) I would still look if the copy works maybe even something like "Select as many products as you want" could indicate users towards the right direction.

2) In the screenshot you provided there are no visible checkboxes on the other two unselected products. Perhaps keeping a checkbox visible, even empty, would be a good indication that those other products can be selected too.

Example:
[image]

3) Change the circular checkboxes to squares. A lot of people, even subconsciously, associate round select options with radio buttons. Radio buttons only allow for one selection at a time. Perhaps changing the shape would indicate better that these are checkboxes (as always test this). [Read more about round checkboxes.](http://danieldelaney.net/checkboxes/)

Example:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. I'm still looking for some other answers on this question/problem.

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: he's right. You need an affordance on the selectable objects. this is about the best answer I can think of

Answer (score 0):

You could consider lower the opacity on the images/tiles. User will subconsciously want to pull the images into full opacity by clicking on them. The same may be said to change the image from black & white to color. Yet another option would be to have the tiles "flip over" upon click. Another potential change would be to remove the checkboxes and rely on learned behavior. I'm making the assumption a good goal would be for the users to "play" with the interface and encourage them to select multiple options.